# How to get values of 2 checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkboxlist

I have a list with checkboxes and I want the user to be able to select 2 of them.
So how do I get the values into 2 variables?
I have this now but it only selects the first one.
So how can I get pushtagsName2 to select the second value?

```
var pushtagsName1=$('input[name=pushtagsName]:checked').val()
var pushtagsName2=$('input[name=pushtagsName]:checked').val()
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method like following.

```
var pushtagsName = $('input[name=pushtagsName]:checked');

var pushtagsName1 = pushtagsName.eq(0).val()
var pushtagsName2 = pushtagsName.eq(1).val()
```

Comment: The second one has the wrong index, should be `var pushtagsName2 = pushtagsName.eq(1).val()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try other selector in jquery like

```
var pushtagsName1=$('input[name=pushtagsName]:first-child:checked').val()
var pushtagsName2=$('input[name=pushtagsName]:nth-child(2):checked').val()
```